# SQL Sequence query next value is last always last value + 10

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a SQL query that creates a new number that is always 10 higher than the last used value (for example company one has number 10 if a new company is added that company will get number 20).

But I get an error and I don't know why it won't execute.

My query is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE anr_num_gen
    START WITH    anr = UPPER(anr)
    INCREMENT BY  10;
```

But I get this error:

> bedrijf.public> CREATE sequence anr_num_gen
> start with      anr = UPPER(anr)
> increment by    10
>
> [2021-09-13 22:51:28] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "anr"
> [2021-09-13 22:51:28] Position: 50

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Higher than _what_ last value? A new sequence has no last value.

Comment: the last value 50 so if i add something new it must be 60 and then 70 so the sequence query looks up what the last value was and then adds 10 to it to create a new one

Comment: The `start with` section is invalid. `anr` is not defined in this place. Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: i have a column in table afdelingen named anr anr is company number so every company has a number the first company has number 10 each company that is inserted always get automatically a new number +10 from the last company so if company 1 is 10 and company 2 is 20 the third company gets number 30 added to its column anr

Comment: Do you simply want `start with 10`?

Comment: yes i want to start with 10

Answer (score 0):

The `start with` section is invalid. `anr` is not defined in this place. Where do you expect it to come from?

You probably just want this:

```
CREATE sequence anr_num_gen
    start with      1
    increment by    10;
```

Or maybe you're looking at the `anr` column in a specific table. In that case, you have to do it in two steps:

```
CREATE sequence anr_num_gen
    start with      1
    increment by    10;
SELECT setval(
         'anr_num_gen'::regclass,
         (SELECT MAX(anr)::bigint FROM "my_table")
       );
```

Comment: i get the error ```bedrijf.public> CREATE sequence anr_num_gen
                    start with      1
                    increment by    10
[2021-09-13 23:11:32] completed in 16 ms
bedrijf.public> SELECT setval('anr_num_gen',  (SELECT MAX(anr) FROM "afdelingen"))
[2021-09-13 23:11:35] [42883] ERROR: function setval(unknown, numeric) does not exist
[2021-09-13 23:11:35] Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[2021-09-13 23:11:35] Position: 8```

Comment: The hint is `you might need to add explicit type casts`. Sounds like `anr` is a different type than the sequence. That or you're not actually using postgresql.

Comment: anr is numeric(2) i just dont know why this error keeps popping up

Comment: Sequences use `bigint`. Try casting to that: `SELECT setval('anr_num_gen',  (SELECT cast(MAX(anr) as bigint) FROM "afdelingen"));`

Comment: That one worked partly it returned 50. but i already used 50 it has to return 60 a new number how can i do that ?

Comment: i got it. ```SELECT setval('anr_num_gen',  (SELECT cast(MAX(anr) as bigint) FROM "afdelingen")+10);```

Comment: do you know a cleaner line of code than that that i can use? that i can use increment by 10 somewhere. i couldt not find it +10 did work though